# IIS 7.5 revealing internal servers IP address on 302 redirect

Tags: asp.net, security, web, iis-7.5

I'm having trouble eradicating a potential security vulnerability. When I run this command:

```
printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc 11.11.11.11 80
```

(replaced the ip address)

I get a response of:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: https://192.168.212.11/account/login.aspx
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 14:45:29 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 158
```

As you can see the response contains the internal ip address of the server and i cannot work out how to resolve this?

Any help would be amazing as this is driving me insane.

Thanks